# Pass multiple InputPaths to a StepFunctions Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

While invoking a state's task, is it possible to specify multiple InputPaths, or 'pick' more than one JSON nodes to be passed to the task's input ?

Example:

`If this is the execution input:
{
    "id":"identifier",
    "nestedObjectA": {
        "doubleNestedObjectA": {
            "valueA": "value"
        }
    },
    "nestedObjectB" : {
        "valueB": "value"
    }
}`
 
 is it possible to pass the following as input to one task: 

`{
    "id":"identifier",
    "nestedObjectB" : {
        "valueB": "value"
    }
}`

and the following to other ?

`{
    "id":"identifier",
    "nestedObjectA": {
        "doubleNestedObjectA": {
            "valueA": "value"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not initially possible using JsonPath, but can now be easily done using [parameters in stepfunctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html).